# How to project a curve on a plane?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have a bezier curve and a plane as below. I would like to project the curve on the plane. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean cut the curve into the plane, of just flatten the curve to the plane?

Comment: @RobinBetts, I think I want to flatten the curve to the plane...not sure though :) I would like the curve to be projected to the plane in the mathematical sense. Right now it is a curve defined in the XZ-plane, it should be projected from the XZ-plane onto the plane defined by the mesh plane in the picture.

Comment: Hmm! Good question! This is trickier than it seems at first. If you convert to a mesh, and are happy with that shape, then OK to; eg; 1. create custom orientation from the target face, 2. set pivot point in that plane, somewhere, and 3. Scale to 0 in Z of your custom orientation. Or: 1 Set snap to 'Project individual elements' 2. Align ortho view to plane with Shift-Numpad-7, and 3. tap 'G'. **BUT**. If you do those with the raw Bezier, it projects the control points too, and the resulting curve is very slightly different.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a non-destructive way, just use the shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

i set the offset only for demonstration purposes. You should leave it to 0.

and here a geometry nodes solution:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Turn on snapping, project on **face**, and **project individual elements**.

[image]

Then select all points in curve in edit mode, press <kbd>G</kbd> and press LMB without moving points.

Comment: +1 to this and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263516/35559). Very probably perfectly  good enough. But see commentary on OP?

Comment: Indeed, it's not a perfect projection (which is what I am looking for). In the end I manually calculated the correct projection and created the projected curve by hand.